# Android wear 1.x vs Android wear 2.0

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I want to create an app in Android wear app, standalone watch app. Initially, I read somewhere that watch apps are not meant to do most intensive work. Like how it looks very tiny, the functionality within it must be simpler. This is my thought as per my basic knowledge that I gathered through reading. But the requirement that I got is I have to create Standalone watch app, which talks to server. The server and app should be able to send messages back and forth. But as a first step, I created a watch app and a phone app. The phone app gets the messages from watch and send it to server and vice versa using Android wear 1.x. The watch I am given now is LG urban 2nd edition which supports Android wear 2.0, currently the watch runs on Android wear 1.x.

Now my question is, since the watch has cellular feature, can I transfer the server connection code from phone to watch with Android wear 1.x itself or Can I upgrade to Android Wear 2.0 and get the server connection to watch app.

What is the best way to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can flash the Android Wear 2.0 preview ([g.co/wearpreview](http://g.co/wearpreview)) to the watch and transfer the server connection code from phone to watch. We recommend that you connect directly from watch to server. In this way, your app will also support iOS paired watches.

Comment: Sure Hoi. Thanks. Can you also please update with the flashing procedure?